# I am having a difficult time putting my sidebar next to my google maps - gmaps4rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, css-float, gmaps4rails

I am trying to put my sidebar with search results next to my google map(I am using gmaps4rails). I got them side by side but the problem is the sidebar does not extend the length of the map see image [SideBar with google Map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVlYU.jpg)

Here is my code in my view

```
<div id="sideBar" class="pre-scrollable">
  <h2><%= @count%> results found </h2>
  <br>
 <% @maps.each do |map| %>
  <div>
    <div class="" id="map_<%= map.id %>">

    <h4>
      <%= link_to map.number, controller: "maps", action: "show", id: map.id%>
    </h4>


    <hr>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Return to Main Map', maps_path %>

</div> 
<div id="map_wrapper">
<div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
 </div>
```

Here is my code in css:

```
#map_wrapper {
margin-left: 300px;
height: 800px;


}

#sideBar{
width: 300px;
height: 800px;
position: absolute;

 }
```

My goal is to have the side by side and the exact same length.

Comment: Try wrapping both in a `.wrapper` element, and use `.wrapper { display: flex; }`. Then remove the margin from `#map_wrapper` and remove position from `#sideBar`

Comment: @MichaelCoker I tried to make the changes you mentioned and it did not work for me. Thank you for trying to help me. I will keep trying to get it right and will update my answer when I do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added my comments to the code.

**Working Responsive example:**

```css
#map_wrapper {
  margin-left: 30%; /* should match sideBar width */
  overflow: hidden; /* cut off any overflow */
  height: 100%; /* fill up main div height */
}

#sideBar {
  width: 30%; /* adjust sidebar width as percentage of main div */
  max-height: 100%; /* Never exceed main div height on small screens */
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #131418;
}

#sideBar span {
  color: #999;
}

.main {
  max-width: 100vw; /* set max desired width for the ENTIRE set up */
  height: 400px; /* set max desired height for the ENTIRE set up */
  max-height: 100vh; /* make sure entire setup height never exceeds device height */
}
```

```html
<!-- initilize map -->
<script>
  function initMap() {var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {center: {lat: 40.674,lng: -73.945},zoom: 12,})}
</script>


<!--Your Map setup -->
<div class="main">

  <div id="sideBar" class="pre-scrollable">
    <span>Sidebar content goes here...</span>
  </div>


  <div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
  </div>

</div>



<!-- Load google API in the footer. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHu4QBgWONqtdOWVLTW5XZ51B1eOU6SWw&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you so much. I just had to make some minor adjustments per your notes and it worked like magic.

Comment: @JermaineSubia Awesome. I'm glad that it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could post the html of the page. Without that I can say, when using elements that are positioned absolute, you should specify top and left attribute values - specificity is helpful for debugging situations like this. Additionally, you should know what they're positioned within. Their parent container is what they are positioned absolutely to.

Another thing I noticed, you have a

```
 class="pre-scrollable"
```

This is not documented in your question, so I'm not sure if this is also impacting the layout.